# Help! Is this object rotation on a displaced surface a bug? I can't figure it out

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, 3d-view, particles, displacement

I'm not sure if this is a **bug** or if I'm doing something unknowingly to cause the issue, and at this point I'm feeling pretty stumped:

**My render is not matching my viewport.**

I've checked all modifiers and their levels and visibility are the same for render and viewport.

If you look at the two gifs below, **they are the identical scene**, the first is what I see in the viewport and the second is what I get when I render the scene.

I'm using the blue disk object distributed on a displaced surface with a hair system including rotation with the orientation axis set to Normal.

I'm wanting the stable rotation as seen in the viewport, not the erratic rotation in the render. **If I turn off rotation in the hair system I lose the orientation of the disks.**

All I can think is that it's something to do with the rotation of the normals of the plane (due to the displacement modifiers) and their effect on the hair objects, not being represented in the viewport for some reason. And if so, is there any way for me to achieve exactly what I'm seeing in the viewport.

P.S. This scene is entirely for demonstration of this issue, I in no-way need anything that looks like this scene, it's just that the issue illustrated here is a lot harder to demonstrate in my actual project.

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

here is the modifier stack on the surface:

[image: Text]